# use final variable in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

i have an error when i give a value to the **flag** variable in this function. actually i want that my intent code will run on second time. how to solve this problem

```
    final boolean flag = false;
    final Spinner spnrContacts = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrContacts);
    ArrayAdapter<String> contactsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SelectContacts);
    contactsAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnrContacts.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);

    spnrContacts
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                        View view, int i, long l)
                {
                    // Your code 

                    if (flag)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(NewScheduleOptions.this,
                                TestActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("selectedType", i);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    flag = true;
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView)
                {
                    return;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean flag = false;
```

declare flag as **Global** variable

for ex:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
   boolean flag;  <---------------
   oncreate(saved.....)
   {
       flag= false;
       //your code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make flag a member of the class. It does not have to be final and it will be accessible in the anonymous class

Comment: but if it is not final, it will give me error in onItemSelected(...) function that it should be final

Answer (score 0):

You want it to run on second time of what? If you mean the second time you start this activity, then your code will fail because flag will be initialized to false every time this activity is started.

You need to store the flag value in shared preferences. First time it runs, save it as true  in shared preferences. Next time,  read the flag from shared preferences and check the flag, if it's true, then it means it's the second time the activity is running and your code will run fine